# Printing floating-point values with full precision with Catch2

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch2

I have some test code using [catch2](/questions/tagged/catch2), that does check wether some computation returns a floating-point null value.

```
CHECK( someFunc() == 0. );
```

The problem is that when the test fails because of very small non-null value (say 1.234E-16), the values are printed with "default" printing, and I see:

```
my_test.cpp:351: FAILED:
  CHECK( someFunc() == 0.0 )
with expansion:
  0.0 == 0.0
```

which is pretty much useless. What I would like to see is:

```
my_test.cpp:351: FAILED:
  CHECK( someFunc() == 0.0 )
with expansion:
  1.234E-16 == 0.0
```

I tried streaming `std::scientific` in `std::cout` just before the test but apparently Catch using another printing method.

Any idea ?

Side note: Actually, I use the provided [`Approx`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/assertions.md#natural-expressions) class but this is not related to my problem

**Edit**: The problem here is **not** about the comparison itself (I know all the evil things about floating-point values), it is **only** about how I can tell Catch to print the handled values.

Comment: If you use `Approx` then show it. Otherwise people might complain about you using direct comparison between floating-point values and how that is flawed. The whole point of a [mcve] should be that it show your problem, and don't introduce other unrelated problems.

Comment: I would have bet I'd that comment ;-) Thks, I know all the problems related to floating-point values, but sometimes, that just happens... And this situation is (kinda) handled by the provided class (see link).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude with `someFunc() { return 0;}` the test would pass, there are some weird corner cases where using `==` can be fine, so the question is legitimate (of course I do agree that a hint about not using `==` is appropriate)

Comment: do you get the same effect on the output if you check for eg `15.000000000001 < 15` ? Maybe you can avoid the floating point `==` issue completely and still arrive at the same solution

Comment: @user463035818 Mmmh, nice idea. Just checked: so `15.000000001` will be indeed printed as is, but `15.00000000001` will be printed as `15.0`

Comment: well thats because i put some digits too many :(

Comment: FWIW, see related GH issue: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/2238

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update***: You [can now](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/commit/92ad9ee355945a4f2b494d1934faaa4bb412ae40) [specify precision in Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tostring.md#floating-point-precision). The following applies for older versions of Catch2.

It looks like the precision is hard-coded within Catch2 itself:

```cpp
std::string StringMaker<float>::convert(float value) {
    return fpToString(value, 5) + 'f';
}
std::string StringMaker<double>::convert(double value) {
    return fpToString(value, 10);
}
```

There are two options to fix this:

**Option 1: Modify Catch2**

If you modify that, you can make it show what you want (note: `<limits>` is already included within catch, so I'll use `std::numeric_limits`):

```cpp
std::string StringMaker<float>::convert(float value) {
    return fpToString(value, std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10) + 'f';
}
std::string StringMaker<double>::convert(double value) {
    return fpToString(value, std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
}
```

A more sophisticated approach could be made to have this be a parameter the user can set rather than hard-coding it to a different semi-arbitrary value, but this is only a Q&A, not a pull request. ;-)

**Option 2: Log it yourself in higher precision**

If you add `INFO( FullPrecision(d) );` before the `REQUIRE()` call, you'll get a full precision print, but only when the test case fails. (See definition of `FullPrecision()` below.)

Both of these changes are demonstrated here:

```cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN  // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

double GetDouble() { return std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(); }

std::string FullPrecision( double d )
{
    auto s = std::ostringstream{};
    s << std::setprecision( std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 ) << d;
    return s.str();
}

TEST_CASE( "Double, double, toil and trouble", "[double]" ) 
{
    const auto d = GetDouble();
    INFO( FullPrecision(d) );
    REQUIRE( 0.0 == d );
}
```

which prints:

```
prog.cc:20: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( 0.0 == d )
with expansion:
  0.0 == 0.00000000000000022
with message:
  2.2204460492503131e-16
```

Modifying Catch2 causes the expansion `0.0 == 0.00000000000000022`, and adding the `INFO()` causes the message `2.2204460492503131e-16`.

See it live on <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kxEoxYmG5Tli1OX0)</kbd>.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that pretty impressive answer ! I'll take a look.

Comment: Accepting, second solutions seems fine with me (editing catch will be a problem when updating). Strange, with your last sample, I don't get what you posted, I get `0.0 == 0.0` (but correct value is printed thanks to the INFO, so it's fine).

Comment: Update: This is [now a feature](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/commit/92ad9ee355945a4f2b494d1934faaa4bb412ae40) in Catch2.

Comment: Re not getting what I showed: I got that because my sample on Wandbox had both approaches. Modifying Catch2 causes the expansion `0.0 == 0.00000000000000022`, and adding the `INFO()` causes the message `2.2204460492503131e-16`. If you did not modify Catch2, you would see only the latter.